# Dynamic PHP pages: to Cache or not to Cache?

Tags: php, browser-cache

Generally speaking, should you do any Browser/Header Caching for dynamic PHP pages?  If so, what setting should you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general rule is: use your brain.

If the page isn't likely to change much, cache it. For how long? Well, for as long as it's not likely to change.

Once the page changes, that's when the cache should expire.

Comment: "Once the page changes, you should send a new version."  How would you do that?

Comment: @Programmer: You roughly predict when the page is likely to change, and expire the cache at that time. I've edited my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: OK, so there would be no way to do this automatically.  Let me ask you this, let's say you have a site that alerts a user to an event no matter what page they are one, and you don't know when that event is going to happen (as it can happen at any time), would you cache any page on the site or not?  If you cache, you might see a cached version that doesn't display the new event notification, for example.  What would you do?

Comment: Well, you don't cache these pages. Since the date is unpredictable, and the state of the page may change at any time. If accuracy is of less importance however, you can still cache the page for let's say, one minute, and "risk" the user being notified up to a minute too late.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, cache whenever possible.  That basically means if you know content isn't going to change, don't spend any cycles recreating or resending it. You'll have to consider each specific situation. I've written up [a full explanation](http://docforge.com/wiki/Web_application/Caching).